# Calculating interest rate from Loan Amount, Loan Term and Monthly Payment

Tags: arithmetic, finance

I am trying to find the equation that the below website uses to calculate interest rate.

https://www.calculator.net/interest-rate-calculator.html?cloanamount=15000&cloanterm=3&cmonthlypay=475.5312917&x=12&y=28

I am able to calculate the repayment amount by following the directions here [What's the math formula that is used to calculate the monthly payment in this mortgage calculator?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/664029/whats-the-math-formula-that-is-used-to-calculate-the-monthly-payment-in-this-mo), but have been unable to rearrange the equation to get the interest rate from the repayment amount, loan term and loan amount.

Comment: There is generally no closed form solution for the interest rate; numerical methods or a financial calculator must be used

Comment: I ended up using the Excel RATE function to get the result I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from @python_enthusiast's answer, the equation to be solved for $i$ is
$$\text{PV}=\frac{\text{FV}}{(1+i)^n}+\frac{\text{PMT}}{i}\Bigg[1-\frac 1{(1+i)^n} \Bigg]$$ which does not show any explicit solution but which does not make any problem using a numerical method.

However, we can make good *approximations*. For conveniency, I shall use $a=\text{PV}$, $b=\text{FV}$ and $c=\text{PMT}$ and I shall take advantage of the fact that $i \ll 1$.

Using Taylor expansion for the rhs and series reversion, we have
$$i=t+\frac {(3 b+2 c)+3 n (b+c)+c n^2 } { 3(2 b+ c)+3 c n} t^2+O(t^3)$$
where $t=2\frac{(b-a)+c n}{ (2 b+c)n+c n^2 }$

Let me try for $a=2000$, $b=1000$,  $c=100$ and $n=15$. This would give
$$i=\frac{823}{39366}=0.0209064$$ while the "exact" solution is $i=0.0213729$.

If this is not sufficiently good, add the next term which is
$$\frac {(n+1)\left(\left(24 b^2+36 b c+14 c^2\right)+n \left(48 b^2+78 b c+31 c^2\right)+n^2 \left(30
   b c+22 c^2\right)+5 c^2 n^3 \right)}{36[(2 b+c)n+c n^2]^2}\,t^3$$  This would give
$$i=\frac{1221967}{57395628}=0.0212902$$

**Edit**

Another formulation

$$i=\frac{-6 ((a-b) (2 b+c))+6 c  (-a+3 b+c)n+6 c^2 n^2 } {2 (a-b) (3 b+2 c)+ \left(6 b (a+b)+6 a c-c^2\right)n+2 c  (a+2 b)n^2+c^2
   n^3 }$$ gives, for the worked example
$$i=\frac{27}{1270}=0.0212598$$